# Multiplying and diagonalizing large sparse matrices without reading entire matrix into memory

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication, eigenvalue

I have a few very large sparse matrices (of dimension on the order of a billion) stored in COO format, i.e. as a list of rows, a list of columns, and a corresponding list of data. They take up more space than can be read into memory on my cluster at once. I need to perform some operations on these matrices involving taking products (twice) and then diagonalize the result.

For my smaller matrices (for a similar problem), I convert the rows, columns, and data into csr format, multiply via '*' and diagonalize using scipy.sparse.eigsh.

I was wondering if there were a way in Python, or perhaps in a different language, to multiply and diagonalize these matrices that involves reading in one slice of the rows, columns, and data lists at one time.

In terms of diagonalizing, I only need to find the first few (let's say five) lowest eigenvalues.

Comment: Here is what a quick google for divide and conquer yields: For eigen I onl found this: [symmetric or hermitian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_eigenvalue_algorithm) eigenspectra and for [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm) things look a bit better. of course you'd have to check how well these play with sparseness... Not sure that will solve your problem but might give you ideas

Comment: It may help to show exactly what you do with smaller matrices with `scipy.sparse`.  Also, is the file data cannonical - sorted and no duplicates?  Keep in mind that all the sparse calculations are done with `csr` format,not `coo`.

Comment: In the `csr` format, values are sorted by rows.  A secondary sort by column may be helpful but isn't a required part of the format.